# pre-increment additions confusion

Tags: c++, pre-increment, prefix-operator

Hello Stackoverflowers,

Considering the following pre-increment addition, can you explain me why j = 8 in the following code ?

```
int i = 2;
int j = ++i + ++i;
//j = 8, why ??
```

Comment: int = 2; what is that?

Comment: no, there is nothing to explain, it is just undefined behavior. You can be lucky that you didnt get a velociraptor jumping through your window as result.

Comment: Ah, typo, i added the variable name.